# How do I order a MySQL query with a count and ratio

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I'm having trouble with the way that I want to order a MySQL query with a count and ratio.

This is the code I'm currently using

```
$getKillers = mysql_query("SELECT `killer`, `killed`, count(`killer`), count(`killed`) FROM `kills` GROUP BY `killer`  ORDER BY count(`killer`) / count(`killed`) DESC LIMIT {$limit}");
```

This is the database structure I am using

```
CREATE TABLE `kills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `killer` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The player who scored the kill',
  `killed` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The player who was killed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `killer` (`killer`,`killed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=680633 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='PVP Log';

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of kills
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('1', 'Player1', 'Player2');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('2', 'Player1', 'Player3');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('3', 'Player2', 'Player3');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('4', 'Player2', 'Player1');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('5', 'Player1', 'Player2');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('6', 'Player3', 'Player3');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('7', 'Player2', 'Player3');
INSERT INTO `kills` VALUES ('8', 'Player3', 'Player1');
```

I am wanting this SQL to use a mysql_fetch_array in PHP to show the top PVP with the KDR (Kill death ratio) which is killer over killed. This is the amount of times they killed someone over the amount of times they were killed.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: So what's the output instead?

Comment: PVP means Player versus player?

Comment: check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ca1/4) for KDR whether this is what you want.

Comment: I want to order by the KDR, so the top PVP players are at the top. The output is random KDR's currently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) 
            FROM kills b
            WHERE nested.killer = b.killed
           ) AS killed_cnt
FROM (    
   SELECT  `killer` , COUNT(  `killer` ) AS kill_cnt
   FROM  `kills` a
   GROUP BY  `killer`
) nested
ORDER BY kill_cnt / killed_cnt DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Sorry, your query makes the webpage to display "Internal Server Error
500"

Comment: i checked it in phpmyadmin - everything works fine, if you have "Internal Server Error 500", check your php error log, and check your php file syntax (php -l your_file.php)